Visiting Mainland France with French Polynesia Visa
I am an Indian citizen, and a permanent resident of the US. I have a multiple-entry French Polynesia visa [in the visa stamp, it's written valid for "Polynésie Française (FR)"]. I have recently completed a visit to French Polynesia from the US using the visa. Is it possible to visit mainland France with that visa or do I need a new Schengen visa?

French Polynesia is not within the Schengen area, so a Schengen visa will be required.

French Polynesia is not a part of the Schengen Area (only metropolitan France and Corsica are part of the Schengen Area), therefore your visa is only valid for French Polynesia and not for France.
A normal French Schengen visa should say ETATS SCHENGEN in the valid for field.

As a matter of fact, Corsica is de iure already part of Metropolitan France ;-)
